# Interesting question in internet

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

[image]

Is this even possible to solve? 
30 is an even number. I don't think there's Answer for this .

Comment: The sum of any three odd numbers is odd, but like you say, $30$ is even, so there is no solution.

Comment: This has been posted before in a different form. There is a trick answer.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800464/what-five-odd-integers-have-a-sum-of-30

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: Why do you believe that every mathematical question on the internet has a reasonable answer?  I presume you don't believe *everything* on the internet is true.  The fact that it looks like math doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without cheating it is not possible:
$$
(2k+1) + (2m+1) + (2n+1) = 2(k+m+n+1) + 1 = 2i + 1
$$ 
for 
$$
k,m,n,i \in \mathbb{Z}
$$.

Answer (score 1):

It says "using $1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15$".

So I used them.

$15+(13-11+9)+(7-5+3-1)$

Also

$(15) + (13) + (15 - 13)$
where I "repeated" $15$ and $13$

Comment: or flip 5 to make a 2

Answer (score 0):

What about omitting an entry? It doesn't explicitly say that I need to fill all three boxes... Though the floating $+$ sign is cringe worthy.

$$(15) + (15) + (\  ) = 30 $$