# Three odd integers from the set $\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}$ that equals to $30$.

Tags: summation, integers

What three odd integers from the set $\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}$ that when summed together equals to $30$ ?

**Note:** You can also repeat the numbers

I found the [Malfunction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800464/what-five-odd-integers-have-a-sum-of-30) question here. But this question has the answer with five integer numbers.

Please help me

Answer (score 7):

Notice that the sum of $3$ odd numbers is odd.

So no solution exists!

Comment: The sum of 3 odd numbers is odd, you mean?

Comment: @Display Name, Do we have any tricky solution?

Comment: @KSKumaar You can take inspiration from the linked question and find that $9$ flipped is $6$, then $6+13+11=30$.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what numbers you chose in the given set, you will never end up with an even number and this is what you need. Think about it like this: I assume you know that the sum of two odd numbers is even. When proceeding to add another term, an odd number plus an even number will always be even. The following link should clarify any other questions about adding (subtracting, multiplying and dividing even and odd numbers).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)